# I can not connect angular controller to module

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I make a rails application using angular JS. my assets folder structure is [assets path structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFIeF.png) 
Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'unicorn'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'angular-ui-router-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-cookies
//= require restangular
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree .
```

module.js

```
var app = angular.module("mofs", ['ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'templates', 'restangular']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('desktop', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'desktop.html',
            controller: 'desktopCtrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }])
    .run(['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies)
    {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'];
    }]);
```

desktop.js

```
var desktopController = function($scope, Restangular)
{
    Restangular.customGET('/current_user').then(function(current_user) {
        $scope.currentUser = current_user;
        console.log('done');
    }, function (){
        console.log('Ошибка при получении текущего пользователя (desktopController)');
    })
}

angular.module("mofs").controller('desktopCtrl', ['$scope', 'RestAngular', desktopController]);
```

when I load root page in console errors appear:

> Module 'mofs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
>   or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify
>   the dependencies as the second argument.
>
> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'desktopCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

how correct include into my project angular and any dependencies? Thank you, and excuse me for my english

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not actually loading your js files. You should reference them through  tags in your HTML in order to be able to use them.